# Crash investigation, recovering symbols from .so file

Tags: c++, gcc, symbols

I have an android application crashing in the native code in some scenario, which I can't reproduce.
I have a vast experience in crash investigation of executables built with visual studio and containing appropriate PDB files. Untortunately I have no such an experience in gcc, however I understand the needed concepts.

I have no crash dump, only the callstack (reported by google play console). It starts from java code, then goes to the public symbol of the .so library, then there's also a callstack inside the native code. Naturally symbols are not visible, since it's a release version, which has private symbols stripped.

I use the standard NDK's build script. In release build on the output I have the following:

- The release-version .so file, ~700KB
- In the intermediate (temporary) files directory:

  - .so file with the same name, 8.4MB
  - objs directory, with various .o and .o.d files

So, I need a guidance how to find out the symbols. The .so file that is in the intermediate directory is much larger than the file with the same name in the release directory. Those files are almost identical up to the end of the smaller one.
It seems that the larger files is actually the same, plus the debug information is appended at the end. Opened it with a HEX viewer and searched for some symbol names (C++-decorated function names) - it definitely contains them.

I tried to use `nm -gC` tool on the larger file. It does display some symbols, but this is insufficient: it contains only public symbols (i.e. JNI methods deliberately exported by the module), plus lots of stuff from std libraries used during build process (standard C/C++ functions, pthread stuff, some stuff related to exceptions and RTTI). But there are no internal function names, which are definitely present in the file.

So, am I missing something? Are there options that should be specified to `nm`? Or perhaps another tool should be used?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "standard" GNU debugger, that is most commonly used together with GCC, is one call GDB. I suggest you simply search for `gdb read symbols from file` and you should be able to get your answer quickly. You can debug a release build by simply loading symbols from a debug-build that's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, [`addr2line`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html) is the tool for this job.  It will look at debugging information and report line numbers and function lines.  There are some options which can improve its output (handling inline functions, demangling symbols).

But you need to compensate for ASLR (address space layout randomization).  I have never seen a Google crash report, so I don't know if it provides addresses relative to the load addresses of shared objects or has some other means to recover relative addresses.  Absolute addresses are very difficult to put to use in this context.